# Execute part of a button only at the first time?

Tags: javascript, html

Without jQuery, I would like to execute a specific part of a button `BUTTON` only the first time one clicks it, which means the specific code won't execute after one has clicked the button, while the rest of the button's code works as usual. How do I do this?

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let num = document.getElementById("num");

function add(){
num.innerHTML++;
//specific code (+5 the first time one clicks the button)goes here please//
}

btn.addEventListener("click",add);
```

```html
<button id="btn">BUTTON</button>
<span id="num">0</span>

<p> first click the button would add 5 to the number, then it will only add 1 each time. </p>
```

Comment: Check the contents and increment accordingly? Keep some metadata around that indicates if it's been clicked at all?

Comment: Yeah maybe you can check if the current text is 0 you add 5 or else you add 1

Comment: I think that might work, thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable that remembers whenever the button has been clicked.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let num = document.getElementById("num");
let btnClicked = false;

function add() {
  if (!btnClicked) {
    num.innerHTML = +num.innerHTML + 5;
    btnClicked = true
  } else {
    num.innerHTML++;
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", add);
```

```html
<button id="btn">BUTTON</button>
<span id="num">0</span>
```